# Depth of Field with object copies/instances

Tags: python, scripting, depth-of-field

My scene has a 3D array of cubes, and the camera is looking at one of the corners:

[image: top orthographic]

I want to apply a depth of field such that the closest corner cube is in focus, while the cubes in the background are blurry. But the depth of field is not working; it seems like all of the cubes are changing their focus together:

[image]

I am using python scripting to create the cubes, and I suspect that each cube instance is behaving as if its location is at the origin (0, 0, 0).

Here is how I am creating the cubes:

```
size = 10
base_positions = [(2 * x, 2 * y, 2 * z) for z in range(size) for y in range(size) for x in range(size)]
base_cube = bpy.data.objects['base-cube']
for pos in base_positions:
    instance = bpy.data.objects.new('cube', base_cube.data)
    instance.location = pos
    instance.scale = (0.5, 0.5, 0.5)
```

I have also tried to create copies of the mesh data:

```
base_cube = bpy.data.objects['base-cube']
for pos in base_positions:
    instance = bpy.data.objects.new('cube', base_cube.data.copy())
    instance.location = pos
    instance.scale = (0.5, 0.5, 0.5)
```

and I have also tried to use low-level matrix operations:

```
base_cube = bpy.data.objects['base-cube']
for pos in base_positions:
    instance = bpy.data.objects.new('cube', base_cube.data.copy())
    translation = Matrix.Translation(pos)
    scale = Matrix.Scale(0.5, 4, (1, 0, 0)) @ Matrix.Scale(0.5, 4, (0, 1, 0)) @ Matrix.Scale(0.5, 4, (0, 0, 1))
    instance.matrix_world @= translation @ scale
```

What am I missing to make the depth of field work? (This is Blender 2.90.0)
Thank you

**EDIT**: camera settings:

- F-stop: 0.3
- focusing on an empty object 9m away
- blades: 0
- rotation: 0
- ratio: 1.000
- scene depth of field max size: 100.000 px

**Edit:**
Note: that the depth of field works as expected if I use the array modifier to create the array of cubes (but I want to solve this using python scripting):
[image]

Comment: What are the settings for the camera (focus distance, aperture)?

Comment: @susu: updated with camera settings

Comment: Did you set the empty as focus? Try a higher value for the f-stop.

Comment: @susu: yes the empty is the focus, when I increase the f-stop, everything looks in focus (but I hope to have the background blurred).

Comment: Find the f-stop that gives you what you want. at 0.3 hardly anything will be in focus.  What lens are you using?

Comment: @susu: I'm using a Perspective camera, 50 mm focal length (default settings). Note that it works as expected if I use the array modifier instead of scripting to create the cubes.